# What is the size of a class when it is inherited from a class which has all its members private in c++?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, layout

Suppose there are two classes Base and Derived

```
class Base
{
  private: 
int a;
}
class Derived:public Base
{
private:
int b;
 }
 int main()
{
 Derived d;
 cout<<sizeof(d);
  }
```

The output is 8. Now my question is when the member variable of Base class is private and derived class cannot inherit it then why does it include the data member when showing the size of the class?

Comment: To put it bluntly, because `Derived` is a `Base`. Access specifiers just control who and where can access something.

Comment: @jrok: Actually, the is-a relationship doesn't hold for private inheritance.

Comment: @abarnert Actually, as far as the *class layout* is concerned (which is the whole topic here), it *does* hold. It can't be any other way, or hell would break loose.

Comment: @abarnert Ok, true. Then the other way around: Derived *has* a Base, always. And if it inherits publicly on top of it, it also *is* a Base.

Comment: @syam: Nope, that's only true for standard-layout classes. All hell is allowed to break loose if the base and derived classes both have members, as long as the compiler can properly keep track of and account for that hell.

Comment: @jrok: Agreed, it definitely has-a `Base` (in the exact same sense that the standard implies when specifying that having a member and a base class of the same type means you "have" two of them, and therefore are not a standard-layout class).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were to have non-private methods in your base class they could access and change the private members, therefore the members still exist as any sub-classes can call the non-private methods.

Private means private, not don't include.

Why have private members in a class with no methods?

Answer (score 4):

The private members are still there, whether they can be accessed from the outside or not - if you don't actually need the members, don't put them there.

Private doesn't mean "remove it if it's not used" - it just means "you can't use it outside the class". Typically, there would be some functionality in the class to use `a` and `b` in a real class - but since this is a minimized until it's no longer useful example, you don't have that.

When a class inherits (private) member variables from another class, they are part of the new class. If they are private, it just means the derived class can't DIRECTLY use them - again, in a real class that isn't so minimized, it there would be a function to use `a` in class Base, and some function in `Derived` to use `b`.

Answer (score 2):

When you inherit a class, your class memory layout is everything that has the base class followed by everything you define in the new class.

You could think that a class B wich inherits from A, is an A plus the new additions of B class.

Answer (score 0):

If base does not have any methods to manipulate the private members, then derived can still not access the members, however, exception is a friend member of base. Make the private member protected rather than private if you want to access in derived. Make sure derived stays as public inheriting base. Keep in mind that derived class inherited all of base class: including private members, however, without any methods to manipulate in base, the private member var is useless unless the constructor does something with it which wouldn't be good practice.

Answer (score 0):

The question actually has nothing to do with inheritance. There is a class with only private fields, no methods and no friends. In effect the fields can never be accessed. Why isn't it treated identically to an empty class everywhere, including inheritance? Most compilers optimize away empty base classes.

I don't know whether it is allowed by the standard, but if I wrote a compiler, I would not optimize such members out. Who knows, perhaps the class needs to be layout-compatible with some other class, perhaps written in another language. I would issue warnings about such fields though.

Answer (score 0):

The actual answer here is a bit trickier than it seems.

`Derived` is not a standard-layout class, because both the most-derived class and at least one base class have non-static members. Therefore, the layout is entirely implementation-dependent. You cannot predict *anything* about the offsets of its members or the size of the class. It *could* be equivalent to a struct with `b` directly following `a`, or to a struct with just `b` in it, or to a struct with `a` following `b` after 69105 bytes of padding.

So, the fact that the compiler is allowed to detect that you cannot ever access a `Derived::a` in your code is a red herring.

In practice, I don't know of any compiler that wouldn't build `Derived` as equivalent to a struct with `b` following `a`, in the usual standard-layout way… but that's just because it's the easiest way to implement a compiler, not because the language requires it.